# Why is the morphism induced by this linear system birational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have seen (what seems to be) the following statement used in a few places, but I am not sure why it is true. Any explanation as to why it is (or is not) true would be appreciated.

> Let $P$ be a point of an algebraic curve $X$. If $n$ and $n+1$ are both Weierstrass non-gaps at $P$, then the the complete linear system $|(n+1)P|$ is simple, i.e. the map it induces is birational.

Since it may be something else that I am not understanding, here are references to what is confusing me:

- In remark 1.28 on page 15 of this [expository paper](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~ftorres/RESEARCH/ARTS_PDF/wp.pdf) by Torres, I am confused about the conclusion "Thus $D = |n_iP|$ is a simple $g_{n_i}^i$ on $X$."
- At the top of page 2 of this [paper](http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~ftorres/RESEARCH/ARTS_PDF/Fuhrmann_T1.pdf), I am confused about the conclusion "Thus the linear series $D = |(q+1)P_0|$ is simple."

Comment: i've scanned the entire net and found zip, except for this: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LUW5hUmXqsgC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=birational+complete+linear+system&source=bl&ots=fdKKqkyDzy&sig=l2I05Wbq3FGyUX8fCVK8JxjWjZ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NSuXVYWRD8PB7AbzqLuIAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=birational%20complete%20linear%20system&f=false, page 125, theorem 5.5 and next page corollary 5.10, but I cant quite get  the text and your question to align!